# php cli and bashrc files?

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

I am working on php terminal emulator, and it works, but its not using any .bashrc or .bash_profile files. So aliases to commands dont work. Im on a shared server which has both php5.4 and php 5.2 so when  i run a command from the terminal emulator its using the wrong php version but if i actually ssh in and run commands its using the right version. I need to use php 5.4 but im not sure how to make that happen.

ive made sure that im acutally using bash

```
/bin/sh -> /bin/bash
```

here is my working (via ssh) .bashrc

```
alias 'php=/usr/local/php54/bin/php'
export PATH=~/bin/:/usr/local/php54/bin/:$PATH
```

however when i log in to my terminal emulator, echo $PATH produces

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Im using system() to emulate, but i have also tried exec() and shell_exec

Comment: ive tried using `putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin/php54/bin')` but that didnt work

Comment: Is the terminal emulator running under a different user than where you have the .baserc/.bash_profile settings set up? Also, you may need to restart the emulator to load the changes.  When you set user settings up, you usually have to log out and back in for the changes to take affect. At least, in my experience! It may depend on the OS.

Comment: The emulator is running as the right user, that was the first thing i thought of... originally it was running as www instead of my user. And i tried restarting the emulator with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is just with PHP (and you do not care about actually reading the .bash_profile file), then you can just call the PHP binary using the full path:

```
$ /path/to/php somefile.php
```

To determine which is the path of the "php" binary that you're executing when you're using SSH, just run:

```
$ which php
```

Will produce as output the full path (presumably "/usr/local/php54/bin/php")

Comment: so this works, however it only works for the one php binary. I have other aliases such as composer, ruby, python so i dont want to have to type the full path for each one of those, thats why i was trying to either set the path or read the .bashrc file

Comment: I am not even sure what you are trying to do is possible. Only option could be creating an external shell script (starting with #!/bin/bash) and execute it from PHP ("chmod +x script", then "./script").
Just typing the full path for each command would be the easiest thing to do, however, in my opinion (you can always have your PHP code to replace "composer" with "/usr/bin/composer" or whatever it is)

Comment: Thats what i ended up doing. Im creating a "shortcuts list" that defines full path so its automatically replaced.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think the $path variable is important as far as what you are trying to do.

If you have php 5.4 installed in /usr/local/php54/bin/ you should be able to run your CLI like this;

```
/usr/local/php54/bin/php -f /path/to/php-file-to-run.php
```